# Do I need to explicitly stop a ticker whose reference has been reassigned?

Tags: go

I'm using `time.Ticker` to do some stuff at a regular interval. I want to be able to change the frequency that `stuff` happens at:

```
for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            //do stuff
        case t := <-newTicker:
            oldTicker := ticker
            ticker = t
            oldTicker.Stop()
        }
    }
```

Do I need that ticker cleanup to avoid a memory leak, or will reassigning `ticker` like

```
case ticker := <-newTicker:
```

be enough?

Comment: From the docs "Stop the ticker to release associated resources."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `JimB` mentioned as per `time` package GoDoc.

Under [`time.NewTicker`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker), the following is mentioned.

> Stop the ticker to release associated resources.

Provided you run `oldTimer.Stop()`, `oldTicker` will get garbage collected after exiting the case statement as it's out of scope.

Comment: In this case, trying to close the channel gives the following error: `cannot close receive-only channel`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593645/is-it-ok-to-leave-a-channel-open) indicates that it is not necessary to close every channel, that the garbage collector wil pick up that `oldTicker.C` can be cleaned up. My concern is that if this runs for a while there will be many `oldTicker`s left around.

Comment: Sorry about that. The answer you linked to is right. 'timer.C' is  a receive only channel `<-chan Time`. The last part of the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `chan time.Ticker` use a `chan time.Duration` and send a `time.Duration` to be used by the ticker's `Reset()` method.

```
for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            //do stuff
        case t := <-newTickerDuration: // (chan time.Duration)
            ticker.Reset(t)     
        }
    }
```

Send the new duration instead of a new ticker and call the ticker's `Reset()` method passing in the `time.Duration` that was received on the channel.
This will stop and reset the ticker with the new duration without the need to create a new ticker each time.  The accepted answer does answer the question, but it would result in increased garbage collection and waste resources.