# Go channel: consume data from channel although not push anything to channel

Tags: go, channel

For example I have this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    c1 := make(chan interface{})
    close(c1)
    c2 := make(chan interface{})
    close(c2)

    var c1Count, c2Count int
    for i := 1000; i >= 0; i-- {
        select {
        case <-c1:
            c1Count++
        case <-c2:
            c2Count++
        }

    }
    fmt.Printf("c1Count: %d\nc2Count: %d\n  ", c1Count, c2Count)
}
```

When running, the output will be:

```
c1Count: 513
c2Count: 488
```

The thing I don't know is: we create c1 and c2 channel without doing anything. Why in select/case block, c1Count and c2Count can increase value ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Close](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close)
>
> After calling close, and after any previously sent values have been
>   received, receive operations will return the zero value for the
>   channel's type without blocking. The multi-valued receive operation 
>   returns a received value along with an indication of whether the
>   channel is closed.

---

You are counting zero values.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    c1 := make(chan interface{})
    close(c1)
    c2 := make(chan interface{})
    close(c2)

    var c1Count, c2Count int
    var z1Count, z2Count int
    for i := 1000; i >= 0; i-- {
        select {
        case z1 := <-c1:
            c1Count++
            if z1 == nil {
                z1Count++
            }

        case z2 := <-c2:
            c2Count++
            if z2 == nil {
                z2Count++
            }
        }

    }
    fmt.Printf("c1Count: %d\nc2Count: %d\n", c1Count, c2Count)
    fmt.Printf("z1Count: %d\nz2Count: %d\n", z1Count, z2Count)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/tPRkqXrAFno

Output:

```
c1Count: 511
c2Count: 490
z1Count: 511
z2Count: 490
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

[For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)

> For statements with range clause
>
> For channels, the iteration values produced are the successive values
>   sent on the channel until the channel is closed. If the channel is
>   nil, the range expression blocks forever.

Close is useful with a for statement with a range clause.

Comment: Understood. So that the reason why we will use close channel pattern right ?

Comment: And one more question is: what is difference between 2 methods: one is using close channel pattern (create close channel, at outside of loop, when done, we push an message into this close channel). And  one is check directly inside select/case block (`case value, ok := <-c1:`)

Comment: Use `close` channel when it is useful. See my revised answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593645/is-it-ok-to-leave-a-channel-open/8593986#8593986