# Go using range to loop over channel, why does it terminate before receiving all the values?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

This code is a modified version of a program from section 8.4 of "The Go Programming Language" book.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

func main() {
naturals := make(chan int)
squares := make(chan int)
done := make(chan struct{})

    // counter
    go func() {
        for x := 0; x <= 10; x++ {
            naturals <- x
        }
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()
    
    // squarer
    go func() {
        for x := range naturals {
            squares <- x * x
        }
        close(squares)
    }()
    
    // printer
    go func() {
        for x := range squares {
            fmt.Println(x)
        }
    }()
    
    <-done
    naturals <- 90
    
    close(naturals)

}
```

When I run this I get the output:

> 0
> 1
> 4
> 9
> 16
> 25
> 36
> 49
> 64
> 81
> 100

But when I change the last few lines to this:

```
naturals <- 90
<-done
```

I get the output:

> 8100
> 0
> 1
> 4
> 9
> 16
> 25
> 36
> 49
> 64
> 81

In the first case, when `<-done` is before `naturals <- 90`, I expected it to print all the squares of numbers 0 to 10, then print the square of 90, then close the channel and end the program.

In the second case, when `naturals <- 90` is before `<-done`, I expected 8100 to be printed somewhere before the squares of 0 to 10, but I also expected all of them to be printed.

Can someone help me get my head around what's happening?

Comment: You are not waiting for the goroutines to complete, so there's no guarantee you ever see that last numbers. I don't know the layout of that book, but I'm sure if you continue there will be some correct examples of synchronization to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to break it down, the first question is why you're seeing 8100 printed first. That's quite simple: the routine that pushed values 0-10 to the `naturals` channel is not started yet by the time you reach `naturals <- 90`. The channels are not buffered, so that routine waits until the value `90` is read by the routine that squares the values, and only then will you be writing the values 0-10 to the channel. This isn't guaranteed to happen all the time, but starting a routine means the runtime (in particular the scheduler) has to do some work. This work takes a bit of time, during which the main routine starts another 2 routines, and writes to the channel. That's why 90 is the first value to go through the channel, rather than 0.

---

Next, you're noticing not all your values are printed. If you want all values to be printed, you should close, or write to the `done` channel when your routine printing the output has completed. instead of having `done <- struct{}{}` in the routine that writes to `naturals`, you should move that to the routine where you read from `squares`. To signal that the `naturals` and `squares` channels are "done", you can simply close them:

```
go func() {
    for x := 0; x <= 10; x++ {
        naturals <- x
    }
    close(naturals) // we'll get to this in a bit
}()
go func() {
    for x := range naturals {
        squares <- x * x
    }
    close(squares)
}()
go func() {
    for x := range squares {
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
    done <- struct{}{}
}()
<-done // now we know everything has been printed
close(done) // always best to close all channels explicitly
```

Now this works like a treat, but we have a problem. There's no reliable, safe way to write our 90 value to the `naturals` channel except for moving that to the routine where we write values 0-10. You could get around that problem by re-using the `done` channel:

```
go func() {
    for x := 0; x <= 10; x++ {
        naturals <- x
    }
    done <- struct{}{} // signal this routine is done
}()
go func() {
    for x := range naturals {
        squares <- x * x
    }
    close(squares)
}()
go func() {
    for x := range squares {
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
    close(done) // done channel is closed
}()
<-done // now we know everything has been printed
naturals <- 90 // now we can write to this channel
close(naturals) // signal to the square routine that was the last value
<-done // wait for the channel to close
```

This works, and will print the values in the order you want/expect, with 8100 as the last value, but it's a bit of a mess. Relying on a channel like `done` here to mean different things is a bit of a pain. We're using it to signal both that we've written all our values to the `naturals` channel, and then the second time to indicate that we've printed all values. That's smelly. Thankfully, we have other means of knowing when one or more routines have finished: `sync.WaitGroup`:

```
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for x := 0; x <= 10; x++ {
        naturals <- x
    }
}()
go func() {
    for x := range naturals {
        squares <- x * x
    }
    close(squares)
}()
go func() {
    for x := range squares {
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
    close(done) // just close it
}()
wg.Wait() // wait for the first routine to return
naturals <- 90 // now we can write to naturals
close(naturals) // we're done, let the squares routine return, and close its channel
// this in turn will trigger the printer routine to return
<- done // wait for everything to be printed
```

---

There's a lot more that can be said about this particular use of channels, who "owns" them, and what routine is responsible for closing which channel, why using buffered channels here might be a good idea (depending on what you're actually wanting to do/accomplish), etc... for now, though, this should help you get going and hopefully shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: "always best to close all channels explicitly": Strictly speaking this is incorrect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8593986/6220193. Also it is hard to achieve in some situations because closing a channel multiple times will panic.

Comment: Mutliple close calls on a channel will panic, true, but as a rule of thumb, I prefer to close my channels when I _know_ I'm not using them anymore. It's not strictly speaking necessary, but when someone is learning golang (and starts using channels), knowing when it's safe to close a channel, and what that means is a good idea IMO

Comment: I disagree. Especially beginners have a need to understand what things must be closed (like a body when making a http request or a cancel/timeout context) and what things don't. Closing a channel right before it is discarded anyway is just extra overhead.

Comment: Swings and roundabouts

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    naturals := make(chan int)
    squares := make(chan int)
    done := make(chan struct{})
    doneSending := make(chan struct{})

    // counter
    go func() {
        for x := 0; x <= 10; x++ {
            naturals <- x
        }
        doneSending <- struct{}{}
    }()

    // squarer
    go func() {
        for x := range naturals {
            squares <- x * x
        }
        close(squares)
    }()

    // printer
    go func() {
        for x := range squares {
            fmt.Println(x)
        }
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()

    <-doneSending
    naturals <- 90

    close(naturals)
    <-done
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Ws7PUDCpvzB)

They key is to have a chain of steps and make sure each one completes before signalling the next that it is done. Same for the entire program: don't exit before the last one is done.

---

Note however, that channels are a synching mechanism. An unbuffered channel can only be written to or be read from when there is a routine on the other end reading or writing to it "in that moment" (it is a bit more complex).

If a goroutine comes to such a point that it needs to wait, the Go runtime will most likely perform a context switch to another goroutine that is ready to be executed. A context switch has a certain cost and is one of the factors why using goroutines to perform tasks in parallel is often slower than just doing all in one routine. One way to reduce the number of context switches is to have buffered channels. That sacrifices a bit of memory (buffer) so that a gourine can write to a channel e.g. 10 messages (when the buffer is 10) before being blocked if the reading goroutine is not yet ready to read from it. And the reading routine can read all 10 messages from the buffer before it is blocked again. If both are reading and writing at the same time equally fast with a few items in the buffered channel, a context switch can theoretically be avoided entirely. (Still the Go runtime will perform context switches to give other goroutines a chance to run their code, given that there are other goroutines waiting)

Comment: _"nothing really happening in parallel"_ isn't strictly true. It's perfectly feasible for a `fmt.Println` call to be executed in parallel with writes to the `natruals` and or `squares` channels. It's not optimising throughput as well as it could (having a buffered `squares`  channel would make a difference for sure), but regardless: channels and go routines are about concurrency rather than true parallelism anyway

Comment: That's why the "really" in "nothing really happening in parallel" 

Comment: it can, though. goroutines are concurrent, which may involve 2 routines running on distinct system threads, and executing in parallel (true parallelism), but they don't have to. In this case, on modern hardware, it's likely that the printing routine will execute on a separate thread, and perform its work in parallel

Comment: I changed it to explain better what I wanted to say.

Answer (score -1):

You're not syncing printer – it may return before it prints everything. So, I'm not sure why 8100 is on the first place, but anyway you may loose values.

Comment: 8100 is printed first, because the main routine writes to `naturals`, the routine that writes values 0-10 to `naturals` is not guaranteed to have started by the time the main routine reaches the `naturals <- 90` statement. The channel is not buffered, so the routine waits until `90` is read from the channel.